# How to get current image index in fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to get current image index in fancybox gallery. There is a `pos` method in documentation but it is just setter method and not working for getter.

```
$.fancybox.pos(3) // works fine
var index = $.fancybox.pos() // does not work . It returns undefined.
```

I understand that `pos` is designed as setter method but i need to know 
current image index in fancybox gallery.
  How can i know current image index ?

Comment: seems like you could try: ("#children_id").val()); as described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/03dfe0f848c38dc5/a1fc8d8a4d51888d?lnk=raot&pli=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following should do just fine:

```
var src = $('#fancybox-img').attr('src'); // Looks for the *fancyboxed* image
var idx = $('a[href="'+src+'"]').index(); // Gets the index of the thumbnail
```

You *may* have to adapt this solution if you use some custom DOM hierarchy.

Comment: thank you very much. Your solution is acceptable But still there is a small problem on this code. You are checking anchors which has same href value but this does not provide correct index because in my own project user can duplicates photos in gallery. Do you have better way for it ?

Comment: Also can you edit your answer for other users because you have forget to add " characters in attribute selector. I have no edit right at the moment.

Comment: Answer edited. The alternative to this method would be to listen to fancybox events and set the index accordingly to these events. I'm not sure fancybox handles this though.

Comment: Still few mistakes exist. I think this is correct way. 

var img = $('#fancybox-img').get(0);
    var group = $('a.group');
    var current = group.find('a[href="' + img.attr("src") + '"]').get(0);
    var idx = grup.index(current);

Comment: For any *other* solution please post a dedicated answer, not as a comment, so that others can profit from it.

Comment: I just pointed mistakes in your solution. This is not new answer or solution.

Comment: I'm eager to enhance my solution if needed. But the one I wrote has been tested and works fine with http://fancybox.net/ Yours doesn't. The only way I can edit/enhance your proposal would be for your to post it as an answer. But I won't force you ;-)

Comment: @AnyOne let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3032/discussion-between-arnaud-leymet-and-anyone)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [FancyBox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) you can use the index property.

```
$.fancybox.current.index
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the next and previous indexes to? I need to extract their links.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write your own method to the Fancybox library (jscript_jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js):

```
b.fancybox.getPos=function(){return p};
```

Then you are able reach the index of actual image by call this:

```
var actualPosition = $.fancybox.getPos();
```

Answer (score 0):

i used accepted answer to upgrade for v3.2

```
var src = $('.fancybox-slide--current .fancybox-image').attr('src');
var idx = $('a[href="'+src+'"]')[0];
```

i needed to find currently showing slide, i needed it for my custom button (to delete that photo)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest and cleanest way to find the current index image in FancyBox 3 :

> var idx = $.fancybox.getInstance().currIndex;
>
> $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').eq(idx).parents('.image_gallery').toggleClass('selected');