# Get current image name/src in Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I would like to know how to get the current image name/src in a callback function in Fancybox 2. I found [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257394/how-to-get-current-image-index-in-fancybox) that gives an answer but it doesn't work in Fancybox 2.

Example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox_share")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
        afterShow: function() {

            // Download button
            $('.fancybox-wrap').append('<div id="fancy_download"></div>')
            .on("click", "#fancy_download", function(){
                var src = $('#fancybox-img').attr('src'); // Solution proposed in another post -> didn't work
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OR, you just use `this.href` / `$.fancybox.current.href` if you want to know the current link (works for any content type) - http://jsfiddle.net/sGaAW/2/

```
$(".fancybox_share")
    .attr('rel', 'gallery')
    .fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        console.log( this.href );

        // OR
        console.log( $.fancybox.current.href );
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply ! this.href doesn't work in my case since I am not working directly in aftershow function but in $('.fancybox-wrap').append...
Anyways, $.fancybox.current.href works perfectly !
I am so thankful ! And thanks for the jsfiddle !
Have a great day :)